# Show there exists $z \in \mathbb{U}$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^n (z - a_k) \in \mathbb{U}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity, circles

**The exercise**

Let $n\geq 3$ and $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{U}$. Show there exists $z \in \mathbb{U}$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^n (z - a_k) \in \mathbb{U}$.

**My try**

Writing $z = e^{i \theta}$ and $a_k = e^{i \theta_k}$, I get that the module of the product is $2^n\prod_{k=1}^n | \sin(\frac{\theta - \theta_k}{2}) |$, using the fact that $e^{i \theta} - e^{i \theta_k} = 2 i \sin(\frac{\theta - \theta_k}{2}) e^{i \frac{\theta+\theta_k}{2}}$. I then need to find a value of $\theta$ that would make this number equal to $1$. Clearly, the function $f : \theta \mapsto 2^n \prod_{k=1}^n | \sin(\frac{\theta - \theta_k}{2}) |$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$. I would like to use the intermediate value theorem, but I have to show first $f$ takes at least one value $<1$ and another $> 1$.

Your help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without holomorphic functions, one can use the well-known fact (and easy to prove by the doubling formula, noting that the function is integrable by calculus considerations) that $\int_0^{\pi}\log(2|\sin \theta|)d \theta=0$.

Changing variables we get $\int_0^{2\pi}\log(2|\sin \theta/2|)d \theta=2\int_0^{\pi}\log(2|\sin t|)dt=0$ and $\log(2|\sin \theta/2|)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, so this means $\int_0^{2\pi}\log(2|\sin (\theta-\theta_n)/2|)d \theta=0$ for any fixed $\theta_n$

But now if $f(\theta)=2^n\prod_{k=1}^n | \sin(\frac{\theta - \theta_k}{2}) | \ge 0$ integrable and periodic on $[0,2\pi]$, the above means $\int_0^{2\pi} \log f(\theta)d\theta=0$ and since $f(\theta)$ is not identically $1$ (as it is zero near $n$ points and continuous) we get that there is $\psi, \log f(\psi) >0$ hence $f(\psi)>1$, so by the intermediate value theorem ($f$ is zero at $\theta_k$) there is $\theta, f(\theta)=1$ and we are done!

Comment: Love you answer!

Comment: happy to be of help -

Answer (score 3):

$f(\theta_k) = 0$ for each $k$, so that it remains to show that $f(\theta) \ge 1$ for some $\theta$. Here helps the complex analysis:
$$
 g(z) = (z-a_1) \cdots (z-a_n)
$$
is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$. The maximum modulus principle implies that $|g|$ attains its maximal value on the closed unit disk at a point on the boundary:
$$
 1 = |g(0)| \le \max_{|z|=1} |g(z)| = |g(e^{i\theta})|
$$
for some $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$. (Actually the inequality is strict because $g$ is not constant, but that is not needed here.)

Comment: I love that (+1).

Comment: I really like your answer, but this exercise can be done (and has to be done when it is given in the contest) without using the theory of holomorphic functions. Thanks!